# Fill time series data frame with dummy zero

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I suppose this is a pretty simple questions, none the less I can't get my head around it.

Consider this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(            
week = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3),     
id = c(12,13,14,12,12,13,14),
x = sample(c(100:200), 7))   
df                           
#>   week id   x
#> 1    1 12 126
#> 2    1 13 166
#> 3    1 14 129
#> 4    2 12 128
#> 5    3 12 136
#> 6    3 13 120
#> 7    3 14 115
```

I would like to create a dummy value 0 or `NA` for `x` for week 2 where there are no observations for `id` 13 and 14. In other words: so that `x = 0` for week 2 `id` 13 and 14. Preferably with `dplyr`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Try [complete](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/complete.html), this post is a duplicate, will try to find the link.

Comment: `df %>% tidyr::complete(week, id)`

Comment: I have reopened this because the answer at the purported duplicate can be simplified substantially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question was marked as a duplicate `group by` used in there is not actually needed here.  Also we have added zoo and several base answers.

**1) complete (tidyr)** `complete` in tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)

complete(DF, week, id)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
   week    id     x
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1    12   126
2     1    13   166
3     1    14   129
4     2    12   128
5     2    13    NA
6     2    14    NA
7     3    12   136
8     3    13   120
9     3    14   115
```

**2) read.zoo/fortify.zoo (zoo)**  Create a zoo object splitting on week and then convert it back to data.frame using `melt=TRUE`:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, index = "id", split = "week")
fortify.zoo(z, melt = TRUE, names = names(DF)[c(2:1, 3)])
```

giving:

```
  id week   x
1 12    1 126
2 13    1 166
3 14    1 129
4 12    2 128
5 13    2  NA
6 14    2  NA
7 12    3 136
8 13    3 120
9 14    3 115
```

**3) reshape (base)**  Reshape to wide form and then back to long form:

```
wide <- reshape(DF, idvar = "week", timevar = "id", dir = "wide")
long <- reshape(wide, dir = "long")

names(long) <- names(DF)
```

**4) tapply/as.data.frame.table (base)**

```
as.data.frame.table(tapply(DF[[3]], DF[-3], c), responseName = names(DF)[3])
```

**5) expand.grid/merge (base)**

```
with(DF, merge(expand.grid(week = unique(week), id = unique(id)), DF, all = TRUE))
```